# Making a Python multiprocessing Pool awaitable

Tags: python, async-await, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I have an application that needs to perform some processor-intensive work based on a websocket stream. I want to parallelize the CPU-intensive bits with multiprocessing, but I still need the async interface to handle the streaming parts of the application. To solve this problem I was hoping to make an awaitable version of multiprocessing.AsyncResult (the result of a multiprocessing.pool.Pool.submit_async action). However, I've run into some strange behavior.

My new awaitable pool result (which is a subclass of asyncio.Future) works fine as long as the pool result comes back before I start awaiting it. However, if I try to await the pool result before it has come back, then the program appears to stall indefinitely on the await statement.

I've checked the async iterator results with next(future.**async**()) and the iterator returns the future instance itself before the pool processing completes and raises a StopIterationError after, as I'd expect.

Code is below.

```
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.pool
import asyncio
import time

class Awaitable_Multiprocessing_Pool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def apply_awaitably(self, func, args = list(), kwargs = dict()):
        return Awaitable_Multiprocessing_Pool_Result(
                self,
                func,
                args,
                kwargs)

class Awaitable_Multiprocessing_Pool_Result(asyncio.Future):
    def __init__(self, pool, func, args = list(), kwargs = dict()):
        asyncio.Future.__init__(self)
        self.pool_result = pool.apply_async(
                func,
                args,
                kwargs,
                self.set_result,
                self.set_exception)

    def result(self):
        return self.pool_result.get()

    def done(self):
        return self.pool_result.ready()

def dummy_processing_fun():
    import time
    print('start processing')
    time.sleep(4)
    print('finished processing')
    return 'result'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    async def main():
        ah = Async_Handler(1)
        pool = Awaitable_Multiprocessing_Pool(2)
        while True:
            future = pool.apply_awaitably(dummy_processing_fun, [])
            # print(next(future.__await__())) # would show same as print(future)
            # print(await future) # would stall indefinitely because pool result isn't in
            time.sleep(10) # NOTE: you may have to make this longer to account for pool startup time on the first iteration
            # print(next(future.__await__())) # would raise StopIteration
            print(await future) # prints 'result'
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I think I have all the essential elements of an awaitable working correctly in part because of the fact that I can await successfully in some circumstances. Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you make it so complex... How about the following code?

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import asyncio
import time

def dummy_processing_fun():
    import time
    print('start processing')
    time.sleep(4)
    print('finished processing')
    return 'result'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    async def main():
        pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
        while True:
            future = pool.submit(dummy_processing_fun)
            future = asyncio.wrap_future(future)
            # print(next(future.__await__())) # would show same as print(future)
            # print(await future) # would stall indefinitely because pool result isn't in
            # time.sleep(5)
            # print(next(future.__await__())) # would raise StopIteration
            print(await future) # prints 'result'
    asyncio.run(main())
```